# Downloading photos from Google Street View and use then for QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, google-earth, atlas, google-street-view

I am carrying out a remote sensing work (land use mapping of the Dakar metropolitan area based on sentinel2 images classifications).
In order to compensate for the absence of a ground campaign and reference data (ground truth), I intended to use photos that can be found on the web in order to preserve this ground/landscape dimension. And to integrate these ground photos into a QGIS atlas composed of several item maps (1 item for Very High Resolution Google QGIS satellite data accessible via qgis plugin, 1 item map of a Sentinel2 data in the dry season, 1 item Sentinel map 2 in wet season, 1 item map of the classif product Esa World Cover. For information, I am attaching a simple screen shot of this existing atlas. For information, the cover layer for the atlas is my polygon layer of the areas of training/validation (reference polygons which are used in the classification process for training and validation).

I would therefore like to be able to add map items dedicated to Google Street View photos to this atlas.
Do you know what ways there are to first save/download Google Street View photos? Will the uploaded photos be geotagged/geocoded?
Then, the idea would be to be able to associate one or more Google Street View photographs with each sheet/page of the atlas.

I'm probably too ambitious.
I saw that there were some QGIS plugins:

go2streetview: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/go2streetview/

streetview: https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/StreetView/

Google Street View layer:[https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/google … er-master/](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/google%20%E2%80%A6%20er-master/)

Up to now, I'm using the Street View plugin. Not other two. Because I can't really manage to use them. The problem seems to come from the Google API key. Maybe I didn't do things correctly.
Do you think these plugins can help me meet my needs?[image]

Comment: You probably have no choice but to get a Google API key (and potentially pay a small amount if your use is very high when you are exporting the maps and making a large number of calls in a short span of time)